# Convert Key Value Pairs in one row to multiple rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, dictionary, key-value

For example I have data like below:

```
bucket_name                               tags
 my_bucket         {'RITM': '0864658', 'AppCode': 'FCKK', 'ApplicationName': 'test-645'}
 my_bucket2        {"RITM": "1117054", "AppCode": "GWRI",  "AssetID": "06634",  "CostCenter": "046",  "ProjectCode": "D20CL"}
```

I need these key value pair of tags column into multiple rows.

Output:

```
bucket_name     Key                 Value 
my_bucket       RITM                0864658
my_bucket       AppCode             FCKK
my_bucket       ApplicationName     test-645
my_bucket2      RITM                1117054
my_bucket2      AppCode             GWRI
my_bucket2      AssetID             06634
my_bucket2      CostCenter          046
my_bucket2      ProjectCode         D20CL
```

Comment: What data type is the `tags` column?

Comment: Tags is Varchar datatype

Comment: it would be a lot easier if that was a proper (and valid) JSON value. This non-standard format will be quite hard to parse.

Comment: is it easy if I convert datatype to json??

Comment: Yes, because PostgreSQL has many json functions to parse json content. See the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_object_keys`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html):

```
select b.bucket_name, v key, b.tags::json -> v value
from buckets b cross join json_object_keys(tags::json) v;
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8bf9d3d77db043be209139a062130bf0).